# Concentration of a random variable in a random sequence

Tags: probability, martingales

Given a sequence of random variables $X_0, X_1, \cdots$. Assume that $X_0=0$ and $X_{n+1}= X_n+U[0,1]$, where $U[0,1]$ denotes a uniform distribution over $[0,1]$. Define $N=\min\{n: X_n\geq 2\}$.

Q: how to obtain a "tight" bound on $Pr[X_N\leq 2.1]$?

Obviously, $X_i$ is a supermartingale, and $E[N]=4$, and we have that $E[X_N]=2$, so one might use Markov inequality. However, I am wondering whether powerful martingale results can give a tighter bound?

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question, but why is it that $\mathbb{E}[N]=4$? [Shouldn't it be something like $e^2-e$?](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformSumDistribution.html) [Eq. (15)]

Comment: @ClementC. I might be wrong: on average, $X_n$ increases by 0.5 each time, from 0 to 4 it takes on average 4 times. But I admit I did not think carefully; will check the reference you give.

Comment: At first glance, you can use (12) from the link above to compute what you want, by conditioning on N, getting the conditional probability, then taking the expectation over N using the probability given in (12).

Comment: @ClementC. you are right, here by the simple argument, one can only have $E(N)\geq 4$, which is consistent to the link. The point here is that I am actually considering a general $X_{n+1}=X_n + N$, where $N$ could be Gaussian, uniform, ... (in general any distribution), so specific result on uniform distributions, being preciser, is probably not quite useful in the general setting.

Comment: See also e.g. [this approach](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1809464).