# What is the expectation of $(1+u_1)(1+u_1 u_2)(1+u_1 u_2 u_3)...$, where each $u$ is a uniformly random real number in $(0,1)$?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, infinite-product

> What is the expectation of $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\prod\limits_{i=1}^k u_i\right)$, where the $u$'s are i.i.d. $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$-variables ?

My first thought was to try replacing $u_i$ with its mean value $\frac12$, giving $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\left(\frac12\right)^k\right)=$ [2.38423102903...](https://oeis.org/A079555), but this approach did not seem justifiable.

Taking the log of the products didn't seem to help.

An Excel simulation with half a million trials gave an average (arithmetic mean) of $2.7201$, suggesting that the answer is just $e$.

Context: This question was inspired by a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4642891/398708) asking for the probability that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^k u_i\right)>1$.

Comment: Yeah, that isn't a justified step.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write

$$
f(x)=\mathsf E_{u_1,u_2,u_3,\ldots}[(1+xu_1)(1+xu_1u_2)(1+xu_1u_2u_3)\cdots]\;.
$$

You want $f(1)$. We have

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)
&=&
\int_0^1\mathsf E_{u_2,u_3,\ldots}[(1+xu_1)(1+xu_1u_2)(1+xu_1u_2u_3)\cdots]\,\mathrm du_1
\\
&=&
\int_0^1(1+xu_1)f(xu_1)\,\mathrm du_1
\\
&=&
\frac1x\int_0^x(1+t)f(t)\,\mathrm dt
\end{eqnarray}

(with the substitution $t=xu_1$). Multiplying by $x$ and then differentiating with respect to $x$ yields

$$
f(x)+xf'(x)=(1+x)f(x)\;,
$$

and then cancelling $f(x)$ and dividing by $x$ yields

$$
f'(x)=f(x)\;,
$$

with the solution $f(x)=c\,\mathrm e^x$. Since $f(0)=1$, we have $c=1$ and thus $f(1)=\mathrm e$.

Comment: I don't quite understand the line with $\int_0^1(1+xu_1)f(xu_1)\,\mathrm du_1$. I guess you're using $f(xu_1)=\mathsf E_{u_1,u_2,u_3,\ldots}[(1+xu_1u_1)(1+xu_1u_1u_2)(1+xu_1u_1u_2u_3)\cdots]\;.$ But $u_1$ and $u_2$ are independent, so I don't quite understand why $xu_1 u_2$ can be replaced by $xu_1 u_1$.

Comment: @Dan: Rename $u_1$ to something else and rename $u_2$ to $u_1$, $u_3$ to $u_2$ etc.

Comment: OK, thanks. Very nice solution!

Comment: Could you (try to) explain how you came up with this solution? :)

Comment: @PhoemueX: I'll give it a try, though I don't remember exactly. I wondered what would happen if I tried to integrate over $u_1$, and I noticed that the expression that results if I plug in a value for $u_1$ looks a lot like the original expression, except for an additional factor, so I figured it might be useful to consider the expression more generally as a function of this factor, because then I can relate its value with $u_1$ plugged in to its other values.

Comment: There are quite a number of answers on this site that solve similar problems using integral equations transformed into differential equations by differentiation (including my answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1373320), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/262421), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1809464) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1818506)), and the fact that the value seemed to be $\mathrm e$ made it seem even more likely that that sort of approach might work, since a differential equation might yield an exponential function.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks!