# What is the probability that $(1+u_1)(1+u_1 u_2)(1+u_1 u_2 u_3)...>e$, where each $u$ is a uniformly random real number in $(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, infinite-product

> What is the probability that $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\prod\limits_{i=1}^k u_i\right)>e$, where the $u$'s are i.i.d. $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$-variables ?

The product, $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\prod\limits_{i=1}^k u_i\right)$, has an [expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4644052/398708) of $e$. I am wondering, what is the probability that it is greater than its expectation.

Excel simulations suggest that the answer is (simply) $\frac13$.

EDIT: After reading @joriki's comment, I ran more Excel simulations, and now it seems the answer is more like $0.328$.

Comment: How strong is your numerical evidence for $\frac13$? I get $0.328\pm0.001$, so $\frac13$ seems unlikely.

Comment: @joriki Before your comment, I ran about several sets of $10,000$ trials each and I kept getting numbers mostly beginning with $0.33$. But after reading your comment, I ran $50$ trials of $10,000$ trials each, and I got an average of $0.3281$. Good call.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see a way to calculate this. If it was $\frac13$, I'd try a bit harder, but since it isn't, there way well not be a closed form.

Comment: @joriki I feel the same way, about trying harder if it were $\frac13$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4644872/398708) is a related question about the relationship between the expectation and the probability.